# Need MsHtml update for new Internet Explorer versions

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, ihtmldocument, microsoft.mshtml

Since Internet Explorer 9 there is a new interface `IDOMDocumentType` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975983%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

These interfaces are declared in `mshtml.h`. But I have Visual Studio 2005 which does not yet have this interface declaration.
And even if this interface was declared in a Visual Studio 2012 file I will not install a new Visual Studio just to get a declaration of 20 lines of code! My disk is already full!

I know that this is not necessary and I can do this easily with Visual Studio 2005 if I add 20 lines to my code.

Can anybody tell me if Microsoft publishes updates for developers for new Internet Explorer versions and where to find them?

If not, where can I find a `mshtml.h` which contains the new interfaces of Internet Explorer 9 ?

Elmü

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer myself.

As it may be usefull for anybody I don't delete my question.

Here is the answer: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22934